# WebdriverIO How to DISABLE "Save Password" popup in Chrome 84?

Tags: webdriver-io

I'm desperate to find this solution because it seems nothing on the web is working atm.

My WDIO dependencies

```
"@wdio/browserstack-service": "^6.1.15",
"@wdio/cli": "^6.3.4",
"@wdio/cucumber-framework": "^6.3.0",
"@wdio/devtools-service": "^5.13.0",
"@wdio/local-runner": "^6.3.4",
"@wdio/spec-reporter": "^6.3.0",
"@wdio/sync": "^6.3.3",
```

Basically I need to disable this popup:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/vHuZg.jpg

I've disabled a param in my chrome:

`chrome://settings/passwords - Offer to save passwords`

observed file

`AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Preferences`

1 pref were added

```
"credentials_enable_service": false,
```

worth to mention that I've tried other values:

```
"credentials_enable_service": "false"
"credentials_enable_service": 0
"credentials_enable_service": "0"
"credentials_enable_service": 1
"credentials_enable_service": "1"
"credentials_enable_service": 2
"credentials_enable_service": "2"
```

in my capabilities I have added the following:

```
"goog:chromeOptions": {
    "prefs": {
      "credentials_enable_service": false
    },
     "args": [some arguments]
  }
```

But popup is still present
and in a chrome created by WDIO I can see that param

`chrome://settings/passwords - Offer to save passwords` - is ENABLED

So my question is whether WebdriverIO passes `"goog:chromeOptions": { "prefs": {} }` to Chrome browser?
It seems that prefs are not passed. Atleast in a form i try because args array work perfectly

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply add `'--enable-automation'` to the `args`.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Updating Capabilities like this works fine in the Chrome browser

```html
    capabilities: [{

        'goog:chromeOptions': { 
            args: ["--disable-gpu", "--enable-automation","--headless"]
       }
    }],
```

Answer (score 0):

I have to disable the info bar and disable this popup . below code works for me in chrome 117

```
capabilities: [
    {
    browserName: 'chrome',
    'goog:chromeOptions': {
        'excludeSwitches': ['enable-automation'],
        "prefs": {
            "credentials_enable_service": false,
            "profile": {
              "password_manager_enabled": false
            }
    }
}
},
```